# How to downgrade Ansible 2.1.1.0 to 2.0.2?

Tags: apt, downgrade

For compatibility reasons, I need to use Ansible 2.0.2.

When I try with `apt-get` I can only find versions 2.1.1, 1.7.2 and 1.5.4.

How can I downgrade to 2.0.2 specifically?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ansible is distributed as a Python package published in [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ansible) and it's better to use `pip`. So uninstall the APT-installed package and execute:

```
pip install -I ansible==2.0.2
```

---

Depending on your configuration (and current state) you might need to install some dependencies. From my experience the following make Ansible work flawlessly. Try first to rely on automatically installed package dependencies, but if you encounter errors, use them as a reference:

- APT packages

  - python-setuptools
  - python-dev
  - autoconf  <sub><sup>(required for `pip install pycrypto`)</sup></sub>
  - g++  <sub><sup>(required for `pip install pycrypto`)</sup></sub>
  - python2.7-dev  <sub><sup>(required for `pip install pycrypto`)</sup></sub>
  - sshpass  <sub><sup>(required for using Ansible with plain text passwords)</sup></sub>
  - build-essential
  - libssl-dev
  - libffi-dev
- Pip packages

  - paramiko
  - PyYAML
  - Jinja2
  - httplib2
  - six

---

You might consider using virtual environments like [virtualenv](/questions/tagged/virtualenv) in Python to keep several versions available. There is more information about Python virtual environments [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).